# mahout recommendations on two event on similar item

Tags: mahout

I am trying to solve a problem on mahout. The question is we have users and courses, a user can view a course or can take a course. If a user is viewing a course frequently then i have to recommend to take the course. I have data like userid and itemid and there is no preferences associated with.
EX:

1 2

1 7

2 4

2 8

3 5

4 6

where in first column 1 is userid and in 2nd column 2 is course id.The twist is in 2nd column can hold both viewed or/and complete of a particular course.suppose courseA which is viewed has id 2 and same courseA which is taken has id 7 for user 1. if a user other than user 1 coming and viewing the courseA than i have to predict courceA to be taken.now the problem here is if all the user viewing a course but not taking it, then user based recommendation in mahout will be failed.because for business perspective we have to give them the course that they are viewing should be taken. Do i need to factorize my dataset here or which algo is best suitable for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that viewing may not predict (and certainly won't predict as well) that the user wants to take the course. You should look at the new cross-cooccurrence recommender stuff in Mahout v1. It's part of a complete revamp of Mahout on Spark using a new Scala DSL and built in optimizer for linear algebra. The command line job you are looking for is *spark-itemsimilarity* and it can ingest your user and item ids directly without translating them into cardinal non-negative numbers.

The algo takes the actions you know you want to recommend (user takes a course) these are the strongest "indicators" that can be used in your recommender. Then finds correlated views, views that led to the user taking that course. This is done with the *spark-itemsimilarity* job, which can take two actions at a time finding correlations, filtering out noise, and producing two "indicators". From the job you get two sparse matrices, each row is an item from the "user takes a course" action dataset and the values are an ordered list of item ids that are most similar. The first output will be items similar by other peoples taking the course, the second will be items similar by other people viewing and taking the course.

Input uses application specific IDs. You can leave you data mixed if you include a filter term that ids the action. It looks something like:

```
user-id-1,item-id1,user-took-class
user-id-1,item-id2,user-viewed-class-page
user-id-1,item-id5,user-viewed-class-page
...
```

The output is text delimited (think CSV but you can control the format) and is all item-id tokens that by default looks like this:

```
item-id-1,item-id-100 item-id-200 item-id-250 ...
```

This is an item id,  comma, and an ordered list of similar items separated by spaces. Index this with a search engine and use the current user's history of action 1 to query against the primary indicator and the user's history of action 2 against the secondary cross-cooccurrence indicator. These can be indexed together as two fields of the same doc so there is only one query against two fields. This also gives you a server that is as scalable as Solr or Elasticsearch. You just create the data models with Mahout then index and query them with a search engine.

Mahout docs:http://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html
Preso on the theory and other things you can do with these techniques: http://www.slideshare.net/pferrel/unified-recommender-39986309

Using this technique you can take virtually the entire user clickstream recorded as separate actions and use them to make better recs. The actions don't even have to be on the same items. You can use the user's search term history, for instance, and get a cross-cooccurrence indicator. In this case the output would have search terms that lead users to take the course and so your query would be the current user's search term history.

Comment: Many Thanks pferrel, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I am posting another problem. I will be thankful to you if you can help me out as well.As I am a new user in stackoverflow so, could not help in your reputation.